# how to change the formula needed without changing the other formula? vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

How can I increment the column reference in a VLOOKUP, so that when i drag the formula left it increase's by 1 each time, without me having to do this manually.

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,'Lazada qty 1-19 June'!$A:$AA,12,0)
```

Would become:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,'Lazada qty 1-19 June'!$A:$AA,13,0)
=VLOOKUP($A3,'Lazada qty 1-19 June'!$A:$AA,14,0)
```

When dragged across.

Comment: The meaning of **drag the formula left** is drag from Right to Left?

Answer (score 2):

Replace 12 with `=COLUMN(L1)`

But be cautious that if you deleted a column to the left of L, this would then change the formula also.

Answer (score 0):

To drag left is slightly more complicated than dragging right. But one essentially needs to do "the same thing" just differently... which will hopefully make sense shortly.

Dragging right first:

*This is really dragging right has the number rise and dragging left has the number fall.*

This is the easier to understand right off. You need to figure how to calculate the correct value in one column, then drag the formula to either side. So, say you are writing the formula in column H (the eighth column). The value needs to be 12. You can make this changeable and dependent upon the function `COLUMN()` (notice there is NOTHING between those parentheses?). Your calculation for getting 12 would be `COLUMN()+4` which in column H gives you 8+4=12. Drag it right and the value of `COLUMN()` keeps increasing so the calculation keeps increasing. In column I you get 9+4=13, in column AA you get 26+4=30. Drag left to column D and you get 4+4=8.

Easy to understand because dragging it to a higher numbered column makes the result higher, which feels natural.

Dragging left second:

*This is really dragging right has the number fall and dragging left has the number rise.*

So, still in column H and you want 12. BUT, when you drag it left, you want the result to RISE, not fall like the previous example. And vice versa.

There is a practical issue that arises in this usage (nothing theoretical, like exceeding the speed of light so you can't use it, just practical). That is that if you drag right, the result falls and when it reaches 0, the lookup function will error (unless you do something outside the question to handle that). So where the first kind of usage here, rises as one drags right, was open ended for 16,000+ columns of dragging, this usage will peter out when the 12 falls to 1, or 11 columns to the right. Not 16,000+. Just something to keep in mind.

Anyway, you need to do the same thing:  calculate the value to use. You just need it to fall when going to the right and rise when going to the left. So you subtract it from some number. Where you added the column number and some value, 4 in the example above, you now subtract the column number instead.

Say you are in column H and you need 12 for the value. To make it work as far right as you'd ever be able to drag it, you need to account for 11 columns of dragging, or to column 19 (column S). In column S, the calculation of "Number minus column number" must equal 1. That would be 19+1=20. So use 20 as the number to subtract the column number from.

That's `20-COLUMN()` (again, nothing between the parentheses). So in column S it will be 20-19=1 and in column H it will be 20-8=12.

Now when you drag it either way, it works as requested. Drag it left and column by column the value rises by 1. So 13, 14, and so on when going left.

So that's the answer to both kinds of need where this problem arises. Calculate the value by:

1. **adding to some base number** to make the **results rise as you move to the right** and
2. **subtract from some base number** to make the **results rise as you move to the left**.